# Confused about has many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Ok so I am building this rails app.  I need a relationship between restaurants and dishes.

So restaurants has_many :dishes and dish belongs_to restaurant  Problem is that the model is called dish and so it is called :dishes.. does this matter or does the name need to be (model_name)+s so dishs  or is this totally irrelevant and this relationship is setk-up in my controller like I am thinking..

Comment: Have you tried it out? I think you'll find it handles `:dishes` as expected

Comment: Yup as Matt says, Rails pluralizes for you :).

Comment: Oh wow cool and no I haven't got to try it out yet.. I have a bad habit of implementing too many features before testing any lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a number of built in plurals and rules. Dish ends in sh so it's plural is dishes and this is what you should use.

If you fire up a rails console, you can check things with:

'Dish'.pluralize #=>'Dishes'

If you don't get the expected results, you can define your own plurals in config/initializers/inflections.rb  (examples should already be there when you edit the file)

Answer (score 1):

Even if the pluralization would not work you can always specify it manually:

```
has_many :dishes, :class_name => 'Dish'
```

Or you can give the association a completely different name:

```
has_many :recipients, :class_name => 'User'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Rails probably will correctly inflect the plural of `dish` as `dishes`:

```
require 'active_support/all'

"dish".pluralize
# => "dishes"
```